# What are the advantages of [Diagnostics.Process] Start() over Start-Process?

Tags: powershell

What are the advantages of using `[Diagnostics.Process]` `Start()` over `Start-Process` in PowerShell?

Comment: The only advantage is flexibility/control - you get to make all the decisions your self! (although that may count as a disadvantage as well)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there are any.

According to [the MSDN for Start-Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)

> This cmdlet is implemented by using the Start method of the System.Diagnostics.Process class.

Maybe calling the method directly is slightly quicker? That is the only advantage I can see.